# Incrementing counter within for loop to sum a simple array

Tags: python

I'm trying to increment an index in a loop for but my program does not work. I have a simple array with 10 elements and I want to sum all elements of this array. I'm having problem, because I consider two loop, first I want to calculate the five first elements and than the five last, but my counter i_i does not change in the program, the code is

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pylab import *


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 ,10]

i_i = 0
i_j = 5
sum_t = 0.0

for i in range(2):
    for ii in range(i_j):
        sum_t += x[i]
    i_i += 5
    i_j += 5

print(sum_t)
```

The valeu of the sum must be 55, but I'm have problem with the index i_i. Any suggestion is welcome to make the program work in this way.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to sum the first five and the last five elements in an array? So do you want to obtain two sums in the end (`sum_first` and `sum_last`)? Why do you do it in this very weird way and not via `x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 ,10]); x[:5].sum(); x[5:].sum()`?

Comment: In fact I want to obtain the total sum. I have trying to make this sum for a big array (in another problem) and I need to make in this way.

Comment: How do you know `i_i` doesn't change?  `i_i` is *unused* in the loop, so its value makes no difference.  Your inner loop keeps adding `x[i]` repeatedly, on the first trip through the outer loop you will add `x[0]` to `sum_t` `5` times.  On the second trip through the loop you'll add `x[1]` to `sum_t` `10` times.  So the result should be `5*1 + 10*2`, i.e. `25`, and since you're using floating point for the sum, it will be shown as `25.0`.

Comment: Tom Karzes, Thank you

Comment: @IgorMelo I recommend checking whether you really need to do this in this way since this is neither very optimised nor a very robust way to get the sum of an array. As you realised by yourself since you made a mistake with all the different indices. Maybe you should ask a question about the other problem here which forced you in the first place to use this strange solution.

Comment: @mrzo Thank you. I'm not an expert in Python. But with this simple question I learned. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong variable in the second loop, it is `ii`, not `i`. Secondly the last loop must go from `i_i` to `i_j` so your range is also wrong:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pylab import *

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 ,10]

i_i = 0
i_j = 5
sum_t = 0.0

for i in range(2):
    for ii in range(i_i, i_j):
        sum_t += x[ii]
    i_i += 5
    i_j += 5

print(sum_t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you hope to achieve by summing in two halves, but this works:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 ,10]

i_i = 0
i_j = 5
sum_t = 0.0

for i in range(2):
    for ii in range(i_j):
        sum_t += x[ii + i_i]
    i_i += 5

print(sum_t)
```

`i_j` means that you want to sum 5 elements each time. `i_i` tells the loop how far forward to start in `x`.

I'm sure that `float(sum(x))` gives the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the i_i index and in the second for you were using i instead of ii.

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 ,10]

i_i = 0
i_j = 5
sum_t = 0.0

for i in range(2):
    for ii in range(i_i, i_j):
        sum_t += x[ii]
    i_i += 5
    i_j += 5
    print (i_j)

print(sum_t)
```

But I would just use this:

```
print(sum(x))
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact I need to do in this way. But now it works very well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are the reasons why above code does not work as expected

1) Wrong index variable in the sum.Have to use x[ii] instead of x[i]

2) Range of the second for loop, first execution it has to start from index 0 and in the next execution, the starting index should be 5.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 ,10]

i_i = 0
i_j = 5
sum_t = 0.0

for i in range(2):
    for ii in range(i_i,i_j):
        sum_t += x[ii]
    i_i += 5
    i_j += 5

print(sum_t)
```